# The Audience URI could not be validated

Tags: 2013, alternate-access-mapping, load-balancing

I have two load balanced WFEs. My site is using Form Based Authentication (FBA).

There is also two load balanced Proxy Servers in between. Let's call my site www.example.com.

So if someone opens my site then it goes like this:

1. Request first come to load balancer of proxy server
2. Let's say request goes to proxy1
3. From there it goes to load balancer of WFE
4. Let's say request goes to WFE2
5. And then finally the site opens in browser.

If I go to `www.example.com/login.aspx` and enter correct user/password then it works and I am able to login.

If I go to `example.com/login.aspx` and enter correct user/password then I get following error:

> The Audience URI could not be validated

I read that this is due to incorrect/missing entries in Alternate Access Mapping (AAM). Please check attached to see AAM entries.

This is only happening when I am browsing site like normal user from my PC. If I take Remote Desktop (RDP) of WFE1 or WFE2 and open site from there after making entries in HOSTS file then it works fine.

How do I solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Fixed the issue by applying correct AAM settings. Here's how I did it.

Deleted "Custom" zone and only kept "Default" and "Internet" zones. In Internet zone I defined www.example.com as public URL. I then added following Internal URLs in "Internet" zone.

example.local
www.example.com
example.com